# Change the view in Java

Tags: java, android-intent, view

I've two images than changes of view. The change to introducirCodigo works ok but pantallaCalendario not working.

**XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/bola"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_logotip_aplicacio"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_logotip_aplicacio"
    android:onClick="pantallaCalendario"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
 <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/nombre"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_nombre"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_nombre"
        android:onClick="introducirCodigo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7" />
```

**JAVA CLASS**

```
public void introducirCodigo(View v){
    Intent act = new Intent(Portada.this, IntroduceCodigo.class);
    startActivity(act);
}

public void pantallaCalendario(View v){
    Intent act2 = new Intent(Portada.this, calendario.class);
    startActivity(act2);
}
```

The error is : "at com.golftipp.Portada.pantallaCalendario(Portada.java:67)"

```
07-11 06:52:21.926    1514-1514/com.golftipp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.golftipp, PID: 1514
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.golftipp/com.golftipp.calendario}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
            at com.golftipp.Portada.pantallaCalendario(Portada.java:67)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 06:52:26.216    1514-1514/com.golftipp I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1514 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Not working how? Please post your LogCat.

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.golftipp/com.golftipp.calendario}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the activity into your AndroidManifest.xml. I bet it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Intent act2 = new Intent(Portada.this, Calendario.class);